# send notification when new child is added to Firebase database

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using Firebase database in my app, and I need to send a notification to the Admin when a new order is added to the database "new child added to the database".
I found something called Firebase cloud messaging but I don't know how to use it.

Any help, please?

Answer (score 1):

The Firebase Cloud Messaging is used to send push notification to a devices or a group of devices.The thing that you want to achive can be implemented by using Cloud Functions for more details

[HERE](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/)

[Codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-cloud-functions/#0)

You need to specify a node which will be trigger when a child is added to a database in cloud function and than in that cloud function you can write your logic to send push notification to the admin

This [Example](https://android.jlelse.eu/serverless-notifications-with-cloud-functions-for-firebase-685d7c327cd4) will help to you start with